# Optional attribute set with React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm about to make the next my page with React and I can't find how to put a configurable attribute set into component, for example:

```
<ProgressBar active now={current} max={total}/>
```

I want to add the **active** attribute inside the ProgressBar only if `current == total`.

How can I do this?

Is there an easy way to switch between two options **active** and **stripped**? Something like this:

```
<ProgressBar {current==total ? stripped : active} now={current} max={total}/>
```

except to create a properties object and spread it {...props}

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If the component handles `false` values correctly, just always add the props:

```
let stripped = this.state.current === this.state.total;

 <ReactBootstrap.ProgressBar
   stripped={stripped}
   active={!stripped}
   now={this.state.current}
   max={this.state.total}
 ?>
```

If you absolutely have to pass one or the other, you could create an object and spread it into the element:

```
let props = {
  [this.state.current === this.state.total ? 'stripped' : 'active']: true,
  now: this.state.current,
  max: this.state.total,
};

<ReactBootstrap.ProgressBar {...props} />
```

Comment: Hmm. I didn't know that **active=false** has the same meaning as the non-existing attribute.
Thanks. And thanks for {...props}

Comment: Well, I assume the component does something like `if (this.props.active) { ... }`, so whether it's not set or set to `false` is the same.

Comment: some people don't like additional attributes where they aren't needed...why be forced to display the attribute. I'm getting into Jest + Snapshots and this is ridiculously driving me to look for answers in threads like this.

Comment: Great example! For the `props` solution where you just want the property, could use an if, e.g. `let props = { ... }; if (needsProp) props['theProp'] = true; ...`

Comment: The syntax `{...props}` is discouraged to use. It's better to use `defaultChecked` and similar react-analogues in case of built-in html-attributes and to refuse to use them in other cases. See https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-props-no-spreading.md

Comment: how about id attriute.   if an element don't want to assgin id  when not provide